# What is meant by the statement: "operator != has been removed in C++20 for std::pair"?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-pair

Exactly the question above. I was reading about std::pair on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair#Non-member_functions) where the following was written:

> ```cpp
> operator==
> operator!=  // (removed in C++20)
> operator<   // (removed in C++20)
> operator<=  // (removed in C++20)
> operator>   // (removed in C++20)
> operator>=  // (removed in C++20)
> operator<=> // (C++20)
> ```

To verify this, I have written the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/oPTd4cj9a), which seems to be running perfectly on the latest gcc compiler, whereas I expected a syntax error from the compiler, so what does cppreference mean by writing `removed in C++20` for `operator !=`?

Comment: Three way comparison can be used to determine any ordering relation if a dedicated overload is not defined. So the text is quite correct, the dedicated overloads are removed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The OP was asking about the `!=` operator, and that's because in C++20 the `==` can synthesizes `!=`. This doesn't seem to have much to do with `<=>`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 - I rather doubt the OP had *only one* operator in mind. But I won't fault someone taking a stab at the literal question and ignoring subtext.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I don't think I'm only concerned with the literal meaning of the question. The OP's link doesn't invoke any comparison operators. Even so, `<=>` is still insufficient to explain why `!=` is valid, the two are not so correlated. `<=>` [is not equal to](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html) `==`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 - Good I addressed relational operations only, would hate to give pedantic busybodies any fodder. You are of course technically correct (the most important way to some), the OP's code link and question only mentions `operator!=`. However, the documentation covers all ops, so the subtext exists. Knock yourself right "correcting" me, I'm out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in what was *added* in C++20, i.e. the `<=>` operator.

`<=>` is the *three-way comparison* operator, also known as the *spaceship* operator. Its purpose is to define all types of equality comparisons (`<`, `>=`, `!=`, and so on) as a single function.

Since the other comparison operators are implicitly provided using the three-way comparison operator, the individual operator implementations are no longer needed and have been removed.

EDIT:

Turns out I'm completely wrong here. `a != b` isn't rewritten to use `a <=> b`; it's rewritten to use `!(a == b)`; see answer to the question that this is marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: Ok, I get it, and it seems that my code ran without any errors which implies that the other operators aren't removed but deprecated?

Comment: @ecneics - No, they *are* removed. The **expression** `a < b` is valid if *either* `operator<` or `operator<=>` **function** is *defined*. Again, the validity of the *expression* does not equate the existence of the specific *function*.

Comment: Oh, I get that thanks @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica and @BambooleanLogic!

Comment: `<=>` does *not* replace `==` or `!=`, it *only* replaces the relational comparisons.